# flatMap function and return type error in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Scala/Spark world. I'm trying to figure out why this code is acceptable:

```
val artistID = rawArtistData.flatMap { line =>
  val (id, name) = line.span(_ != '\t')
  if (name.isEmpty) {
    None
  } else {
    try {
      Some(id.toInt, name.trim)
    } catch {
      case e: NumberFormatException => None
    }
  }
}
```

And this is not:

```
val artistID = rawArtistData.flatMap { line =>
  val (id, name) = line.span(_ != '\t')
  if (name.isEmpty) {
    None
  } else {
    try {
      (id.toInt, name.trim)
    } catch {
      case e: NumberFormatException => None
    }
  }
}
```

I know it has to do with type mismatch, but that is about it. My question is why can't I return a tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what's going on, let's make the types clear:

```
  if (name.isEmpty) {
    None // Option[Nothing]
  } else {
    try {
      Some(id.toInt, name.trim) // Option[(Int, String)]
    } catch {
      case e: NumberFormatException => None // Option[Nothing]
    }
  }
```

Nothing is the bottom type, and anything that you try to merge with a `Nothing` succeds. So the unification between `None` and `Some(...)` always works - try it yourself with `List(None, Some(...))`, which will always result in a `List[Option[...]]` type.

Now if you have a tuple in there

```
    try {
      Some(id.toInt, name.trim) // (Int, String)
    } catch {
      case e: NumberFormatException => None // Option[Nothing]
    }
```

The compiler will try to unify `(Int, String)` and `Option[Nothing]` ... which it can't. Well, It kinda can, because the supertype of any two things in Scala is always `Any` - but that doesn't help you. So that's why you get the error message, because a tuple != an option

Answer (score 2):

`flatMap` method requires a function `f` with a following signature:

```scala
(T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U]
```

Neither `(_, _)` nor `Option[(_, _)]` is `TraversableOnce` but the companion object of the latter one has an implicit `option2Iterable` method:

```scala
def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A]
```

and `Iterable[_]` is `TraversableOnce[_]`. This is why you can return `Option` and you cannot return plain `Tuple2[_, _]`.

In practice you simplify this with `Try`:

```scala
import scala.util.Try

rawArtistData.flatMap { line => Try {
  line.span(_ != '\t') match {
    case (id, name) => (id.toInt, name)
  }
}.toOption }
```

Answer (score 1):

This has not so much to do with Spark, but rather with Scala or functional programming in general. The flatMap operations flattens the underlying structure. For example, `List[List[A]]` to `List[A]`, or `Option[Option[A]]` to `Option[A]`. Likewise `RDD[List[A]]` to `RDD[A]` and it will skip the rows which are `RDD[None]`.

Using a Flatmap here is not really intuitive, you could also first do a map, and then a filter operation. This might look more expensive by using two operations, but since they are monadic, Spark will optimise the operation under the hood, especially using the new [Tungsten engine](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/23/apache-spark-as-a-compiler-joining-a-billion-rows-per-second-on-a-laptop.html).